# Laravel authentication with Ardent, Entrust & Confide

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I had a Laravel 4.2 app with custom authentication through Confide. I have upgraded to Laravel 5.5 and Confide has no support for it.

Now I wanted to make use of Laravels native authentication, however I can't run `Auth::attempt()` because it is expecting

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

but I already have

```
class User extends Ardent
```

Is there some simple solution without needing to do something extreme like push all validation to validation request classes and getting rid of Ardent? (it is a large scale app, so it would require significant refactor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue with interfaces and traits, so now I have `User` model like this:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;


class User extends Ardent implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable;
    ...
}
```